# SpreadSheetApp append value to a specific cell using JS

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanna create a function to append (or edit) a value in a specific cell of my spreadSheet; for example where the Name is "Amirhossein" and also the Month is "Jan", append value x into the existing cell of column Items.

First state:

[image: before calling function]

and after calling f("Amirhossein", "Jan", "x") should be like this:

[image: after calling function]

using the below code, a new row will be add in my sheet:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById("myId").getSheetByName("mySheet").appendRow(["Amirhossein", "Jan", "x"]);
```

but I want to consider these two columns (Name and Month) as primary key of my table.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to add `x` at the column "C" of the row that the values of column "A" and "B" are `Amirhossein` and `Jan` by running `f("Amirhossein", "Jan", "x")`.

  - If the value of the column "C" is `a, b`, you want to add `x` like `a, b, x`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please copy and paste it to the script editor of the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, and set the Spreadsheet ID and sheet name, then run `run()`. By this, `x` is added to the value of column "C" at the row that the values of column "A" and "B" are `Amirhossein` and `Jan`.

```
function f(v1, v2, v3) {
  var spreadsheetId = "myId"; // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheetName = "mySheet"; // Please set sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var updatedValues = values.map(function(e) {return [e[0] == v1 && e[1] == v2 ? (e[2] ? e[2] + ", " + v3 : v3) : e[2]]});
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, updatedValues.length, updatedValues[0].length).setValues(updatedValues);
}

// Please run this.
function run() {
  f("Amirhossein", "Jan", "x");
}
```

#### Note:

- From your script in your question, in the sample script, I used `openById()` and `getSheetByName()`.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.